# Is $\log(3^n) = O(\log(2^n))$?

Tags: asymptotics

How can I prove that this is true/false:

$$\log(3^n) \in O(\log(2^n))\ ?$$

I know $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ if there are positive constants $C$ and $k$ such that: $$f(n) \le C \cdot g(n)$$ whenever $n > k$.

I think that the plot shows that it is not in $O(\log(2^n))$. Can I prove it with $$0 \leq \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{g(n)}{f(n)} < \infty\ ?$$
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks, I found the answer, the hint that it is a linear function help me! It is true for big-O and also true for big-$\Omega$.

Comment: Note that $\log(a^n)=n\log a$ is a linear function.

Comment: You could prove it with the limit you suggest because the fraction is always constant.

Answer (score 10):

$$
\log(3^n) = n \log(3)
= n \log(3) \frac{\log(2)}{\log(2)}
= n \log(2) \frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)}
= C \log(2^n)
$$

Comment: Thanks! I don't really understand this part: $= n \log(3) \frac{\log(2)}{\log(2)} = n \log(2) \frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)}$ looks like a change of the base.

Comment: @Cal, it's not a change of the base, just commutativity of multiplication: $\log(3) \log(2)= \log(2)\log(3)$.